# AndroidStudioでの既存のＤＢの使用方法

Tags: android-studio, database, 文字コード

#### 前提・実現したいこと

AndroidStudioでJavaを使ってアプリを作成しております。
既存のSQLiteデータベースを読み込み、その１カラムをスピナーに表示したいと思っています。
その実装方法について（CursorAdapterなど）については調べがついたのですが、データベースをassetフォルダの中に入れる際 `File was loaded wrong encoding:UTF-8` と表示され、解決策が分からずにいます。

流れとしては
メモ帳に「`CREATE~`」「`INSERT~`」とSQLを定義し(UTF-8で保存)、それをコマンドプロンプトに
コピー＆ペーストしてデータベースを作成します。その後データベースファイルをassetフォルダ内に移動した結果、この問題が発生しました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

エラーメッセージ

```
File was loaded wrong encoding:UTF-8
```

#### 試したこと

メモ帳の文字コードがANSIになっていたので、「名前を付けて保存」でUTF-8に変えた。
SQLiteで `pragma encoding=utf8` と入力した。

Comment: メモ帳でUTF-8を選択すると「BOM付きの」UTF-8形式になり、これが問題を引き起こす場合があります([参考](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=メモ帳+utf-8+bom&oq=メモ帳+utf-8+bom))。
今回の原因がBOMであれば、メモ帳以外のエディタを使ってBOM無しのUTF-8形式(つまり、一般的なUTF-8形式)で保存してみると解消するのではと考えます。

Comment: TeraPatというエディタで試してみましたが、できませんでした。メモ帳のテキストをそのままコピー＆ペーストしてTeraPad上で文字コードを指定したのですがそれだと変更することが出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: また、どの時点での文字コードがutf-8ではなくなっているのかが分かりません。TeraPadでSQL文を作成しているときでしょうか？Sqliteでデータベースにテーブルを登録しているときでしょうか？androidのassetフォルダ内にデータベースファイルを移動したときでしょうか？

Comment: 「本当にBOM付きUTF-8が原因となっているのであれば」エディタでエンコードを指定して保存した時点です。ただし、BOM付きUTF-8が原因であるというのはあくまで可能性のうちのひとつです(ので、BOM無しUTF-8でファイルを作成すれば必ず解決する、とは限りません)。ちなみにTeraPadでは**UTF-8N**を指定して保存すればよいそうです([参考](http://creating-homepage.com/archives/97))。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。TeraPadで「UTF-8N」を指定して保存してコマンドラインでSQL文を実行しましたが、問題は解決しませんでした。どうやら原因がBOMではなかったようです。

Comment: あるいはSQLiteで作成したデータベースが自動的にUTF-8以外の文字コードの内容に切り替わっていたりするのでしょうか？